# Javascript convention: switch statement in object constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, switch-statement

I am wondering my approach is valid/bestpractice for this situation:
I construct a marker like this in angular factory. Instead of extending the marker for each type i use a switch statement that switches the type of the marker. The type determines the icon of the marker.

```
engine.factory('marker', ['map', function (map) {

 return function constructMarker(position, id, type) {

this.id = id;
this.position = position;

switch (type) {
  case 'assigned':
    this.icon = greenMarker;
    break;
  case 'unassigned':
    this.icon = redMarker;
    break;
  default:
    throw new Error(type + 'is an invalid marker type');
    break;
  }

    return L.marker(this.position, {icon: this.icon}).addTo(map.layers[type]);
  };
}]);
```

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one little bit more elegant:

```
engine.factory('marker', ['map', function (map) {
    return function constructMarker(position, id, type) {
        var types = {
            'assygned':{
                icon: greenMarker
            },
            'unassigned':{
                icon: redMarker
            }     
        }

        if(!types[type]){
            throw new Error(type + 'is an invalid marker type');
        }

        this.id = id;
        this.position = position;    

        return L.marker(this.position, {icon: types[type].icon}).addTo(map.layers[type]);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: @user3396016 at least in your case this syntax is "easier" then `switch-case` syntax (imho)